# "Excon::Error::Forbidden" error when trying to save files to Google Cloud Storage with Fog and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog

I'm using Carrierwave and Fog to store images on the cloud. I was previously using Amazon S3 for the actual storage, which worked with no issues. But I switched over to Google Cloud Storage, and now I'm getting the following error whenever I try to save anything:

> Excon::Error::Forbidden in GalleriesController#create
>
> Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body => "`InvalidSecurity`The
>   provided security credentials are not valid.Request
>   was not signed or contained a malformed signature"
>   :cookies => [ ] :headers => { "Alt-Svc" => "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000;
>   quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339;
>   quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"43,42,39,38,35\""
>   "Content-Length" => "224" "Content-Type" => "application/xml;
>   charset=UTF-8" "Date" => "Tue, 01 May 2018 22:03:23 GMT" "Server" =>
>   "UploadServer" "Vary" => "Origin" "X-GUploader-UploadID" =>
>   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
>   } :host => "[directory].storage.googleapis.com" :local_address
>   => "xxx.xxx.x.xxx" :local_port => xxxxx :path => "/uploads%2Fimage.png" :port => 443 :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
>   :remote_ip => "xxx.xxx.x.xx" :status => 403 :status_line => "HTTP/1.1
>   403 Forbidden\r\n"

**initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:                         'Google',
    google_storage_access_key_id:     'GOOGxxxxxxxxxxx',
    google_storage_secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  #config.fog_public     = false
  #config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" }
end
```

**Uploader**

```
class PhotoFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def fix_exif_rotation
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.tap(&:auto_orient)
    end
  end

  process :fix_exif_rotation
  process :resize_to_fit => [800, 56000]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [300, 56000]
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "fog-google"
gem "google-api-client", "> 0.8.5", "< 0.9"
gem "mime-types"
```

It seems like there's a problem with the key_id or secret_key, but I just copied and pasted both from the Interoperability section on the Google Cloud Storage Settings page. And I have no idea how to test if they're valid. My request is from localhost, if that matters.

I've found a few similar errors on SO, but they're all related to Amazon, and they don't seem to apply to what I'm doing.

Anyone have any ideas for how I can debug this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a valid directory name in for_directory.

Replace `config.fog_directory = '[directory]'`
with `config.fog_directory = 'name_of_fog_folder'`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I was just using "[directory]" as a stand-in for the actual bucket name, since it's confidential. I changed it to x's to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error, it seems the host is the reason your call is forbidden. AFAIK, the host should be written as [such](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2142) within your configuration. I believe that the error message is not explicit enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a name that exists, instead of inserting a random name. Try re-installing some of the files that you need to run the program, as I once was doing the same thing but the file had been updated so it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "name", but all of my credentials are correct, I quadruple checked. I tried reinstalling all my necessary gems, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-storage) Ruby library to debug your authentication. Just write a simple script that uploads and downloads a file. There are examples in [this guide](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-storage/v1.13.0/google/cloud/storage).

If you want to use google-cloud-storage in a new Rails application, you can do so with [Active Storage](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#google-cloud-storage-service).